# Why are all words in <p> tags capitalized?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Every word in all my sentences is capitalized for some reason. I will put my html and css down below. Any is very much appreiciated. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>complete responsive coffee shop website design</title>

    <!-- font awesome cdn link  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

    <!-- custom css file link  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    
<!-- header section starts  -->

<header class="header">

    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
    </a>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html">home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
        <a href="menu.html">menu</a>
        <a href="products.html">products</a>
        <a href="review.html">review</a>
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
        <a href="blogs.html">blogs</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="icons">
        <div class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></div>
        <div class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-btn"></div>
        <div class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-btn"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="search here...">
        <label for="search-box" class="fas fa-search"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-items-container">
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/cart-item-1.png" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>cart item 01</h3>
                <div class="price">$15.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/cart-item-2.png" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>cart item 02</h3>
                <div class="price">$15.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/cart-item-3.png" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>cart item 03</h3>
                <div class="price">$15.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/cart-item-4.png" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>cart item 04</h3>
                <div class="price">$15.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">checkout now</a>
    </div>

</header>

<!-- header section ends -->

<!-- blogs section starts  -->

<section class="blogs" id="blogs">

    <h1 class="heading"> our <span>blogs</span> </h1>

    <div class="box-container">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/come.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">Where Does Your Coffee Come From? 5 Must-Taste Coffee Origins From Around The World</a>
                <span>by admin / 6th November, 2021</span>
                <p>If you haven’t tried these must-taste coffee origins, you might want to wait before crowing a personal favorite coffee growing country..</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/perfect.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">7 Essential Coffee Recommendations for a Perfect Espresso</a>
                <span>by admin / 30th October, 2021</span>
                <p>Brewing up a perfect espresso is a lifelong journey. With these seven recommendations, you’ll get a lot closer.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/12.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">The 12 Most Common French Press Coffee Questions, Answered</a>
                <span>by admin / 23thr October, 2021</span>
                <p>How much coffee should you use? How long does it take? Get all your french press coffee questions answered here!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/mill.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">Hario Mini Mill Mod Guide: A Must-Do For This Coffee Grinder</a>
                <span>by admin / 16th October, 2021</span>
                <p>The beloved Hario Mini Mill is a fixture in the coffee world. This simple mod makes it even better.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/french.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">A Review Of The Kohipress, A Portable French Press And Travel Mug</a>
                <span>by admin / 9th October, 2021</span>
                <p>How does the Kohipress, a portable french press and travel mug, hold up under close examination? Discover this clever brewer’s strengths and weaknesses here.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/filter.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">3 Reasons I Love Coffee Sock’s Cloth Filters (+ How To Brew Coffee With Them)</a>
                <span>by admin / 2nd October, 2021</span>
                <p>These cloth filters from Coffee Sock have shaken up my regular coffee routine quite a bit. Here are 3 reasons I love using them.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/pure.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">I Tried Pure Kopi Luwak Coffee (Cat Poop Coffee). Here’s Why You Should Too</a>
                <span>by admin / 25th September, 2021</span>
                <p>Would you drink coffee that had been pooped out of a cat (aka, kopi luwak)? I did. Here’s how it went…</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/beans.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">10 Awesome Uses for Old Coffee Beans</a>
                <span>by admin / 18th September, 2021</span>
                <p>Everyone has old coffee beans laying around. Check out these 10 awesome uses for them, ground or whole!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/storage.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">I’ve Found The Best Coffee Storage Container, And I’ll Never Need Another</a>
                <span>by admin / 11th September, 2021</span>
                <p>I’ve gone back and forth on many coffee storage containers, but I’ve finally found the silver bullet: the Ankomn Turn-N-Seal.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/reflux.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">Have Acid Reflux? Don’t Stop Drinking Coffee – Try This Instead</a>
                <span>by admin / 4th September, 2021</span>
                <p>Everyone says to stop drinking coffee if you have acid reflux. Don’t listen to them! There are other, better ways to enjoy your daily brew without damaging your esophagus. Let us show you.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/cyber.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">The Best Specialty Coffee Black Friday & Cyber Monday Deals Of 2021</a>
                <span>by admin / 28th August, 2021</span>
                <p>It’s the perfect time to try out some new coffee gear and beans – and this list of specialty coffee Black Friday and Cyber Monday deals should help you do so without breaking the bank.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/press.webp" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="#" class="title">Bodum Brazil French Press Review</a>
                <span>by admin / 21st August, 2021</span>
                <p>The Bodum Brazil is a french press that has withstood the test of time and is one of the most respected and used presses in the world. How does it perform?</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>

</section>

<!-- blogs section ends -->

<!-- footer section starts  -->

<section class="footer">

    <div class="share">
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-pinterest"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">menu</a>
        <a href="#">products</a>
        <a href="#">review</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <a href="#">blogs</a>
    </div>

    <div class="credit">created by <span>Landon Byrd</span> | 2021 all rights reserved</div>

</section>

<!-- footer section ends -->
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

:root{
    --main-color:#d3ad7f;
    --black:#13131a;
    --bg:#010103;
    --border:.1rem solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

*{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none; border:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: .2s linear;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-padding-top: 9rem;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: .8rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: transparent;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5rem;
}

body{
    background: var(--bg);
}

section{
    padding:2rem 7%;
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.heading span{
    color:var(--main-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:.9rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color:#fff;
    background: var(--main-color);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover{
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.header{
    background: var(--bg);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding:1.5rem 7%;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    position: fixed;
    top:0; left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header .logo img{
    height: 6rem;
}

.header .navbar a{
    margin:0 1rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.header .navbar a:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
    border-bottom: .1rem solid var(--main-color);
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.header .icons div{
    color:#fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.header .icons div:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

#menu-btn{
    display: none;
}

.header .search-form{
    position: absolute;
    top:115%; right: 7%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
}

.header .search-form.active{
    transform: scaleY(1);
}

.header .search-form input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:var(--black);
    padding:1rem;
    text-transform: none;
}

.header .search-form label{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--black);
}

.header .search-form label:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%; right: -100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
    width: 35rem;
    background: #fff;
    padding:0 1.5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container.active{
    right: 0;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item{
    position: relative;
    margin:2rem 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    top:1rem; right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--black);
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .fa-times:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item img{
    height: 7rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .content h3{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:var(--black);
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .content .price{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container .btn{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.home{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:url(../images/home-img.jpeg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.home .content{
    max-width: 60rem;
}

.home .content h3{
    font-size: 6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
}

.home .content p{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 1.8;
    padding:1rem 0;
    color:#eee;
}

.about .row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:var(--black);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about .row .image{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
}

.about .row .image img{
    width: 100%;
}
.about .row .content{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    padding:2rem;
}

.about .row .content h3{
    font-size: 3rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.about .row .content p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:1rem 0;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

.menu .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.menu .box-container .box{
    padding:5rem;
    text-align: center;
    border:var(--border);    
}

.menu .box-container .box img{
    height: 10rem;
}

.menu .box-container .box h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.menu .box-container .box .price{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding:.5rem 0;
}

.menu .box-container .box .price span{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.menu .box-container .box:hover{
    background:#fff;
}

.menu .box-container .box:hover > *{
    color:var(--black);
}

.products .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box{
    text-align: center;
    border:var(--border);
    padding: 2rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .icons a{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border:var(--border);
    color:#fff;
    margin:.3rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .icons a:hover{
    background:var(--main-color);
}

.products .box-container .box .image{
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.products .box-container .box .image img{
    height: 25rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content h3{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .stars{
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .stars i{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.products .box-container .box .content .price{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .price span{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.review .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.review .box-container .box{
    border:var(--border);
    text-align: center;
    padding:3rem 2rem;
}

.review .box-container .box p{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:2rem 0;
}

.review .box-container .box .user{
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.review .box-container .box h3{
    padding:1rem 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.review .box-container .box .stars i{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.contact .row{
    display: flex;
    background:var(--black);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap:1rem;
}

.contact .row .map{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.contact .row form{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    padding:5rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact .row form h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.contact .row form .inputBox{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    background:var(--bg);
    border:var(--border);
}

.contact .row form .inputBox span{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.contact .row form .inputBox input{
    width: 100%;
    padding:2rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: none;
    background:none;
}

.blogs .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box{
    border:var(--border);    
}

.blogs .box-container .box .image{
    height: 25rem;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .image img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.blogs .box-container .box:hover .image img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content{
    padding:2rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content .title{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color:#fff;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content .title:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content span{
    color:var(--main-color);
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.footer{
    background:var(--black);
    text-align: center;
}

.footer .share{
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.footer .share a{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    border:var(--border);
    margin:.3rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.footer .share a:hover{
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.footer .links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding:2rem 0;
    gap:1rem;
}

.footer .links a{
    padding:.7rem 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    border:var(--border);
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer .links a:hover{
    background:var(--main-color);
}

.footer .credit{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding:1.5rem;
}

.footer .credit span{
    color:var(--main-color);
}


/* media queries  */
@media (max-width:991px){

    html{
        font-size: 55%;
    }

    .header{
        padding:1.5rem 2rem;
    }

    section{
        padding:2rem;
    }

}

@media (max-width:768px){

    #menu-btn{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .header .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:100%; right: -100%;
        background: #fff;
        width: 30rem;
        height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
    }

    .header .navbar.active{
        right:0;
    }

    .header .navbar a{
        color:var(--black);
        display: block;
        margin:1.5rem;
        padding:.5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .header .search-form{
        width: 90%;
        right: 2rem;
    }

    .home{
        background-position: left;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .home .content h3{
        font-size: 4.5rem;
    }

    .home .content p{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

}

@media (max-width:450px){

    html{
        font-size: 50%;
    }

}
```

It does this on all text inside the p tags, I have tried to locate the problem, but I can not seem to find what is causing it. It is a multi page site, I just gave one page of my html as an example. But it does it on all pages.

Comment: It's a CSS rule `text-transform: uppercase;`

Comment: `*{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}`
* applies to everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are several instances of text-transform in the CSS.

The `text-transform: capitalize` with the * (i.e.everything) will just try to make the first character of every word into a capital letter unless the `text-transform` property is given a different setting for a more specific selector.

This is not your main problem, though it is quite possibly something you want to look at if it is affecting text further down from your header.

The CSS for header you have shown has `text-transform: uppercase` in a couple of places and this would appear to be the main problem here.

I can't tell from the context given what the overall context of this application is and why it was thought necessary to do these two types of capitalization. Removing both types from the CSS could be a useful start, reapplying them only as needed in a less global way.